# Blinking cursor on active links

Tags: html, css

When I click on a link, this cursor remains blinking on active link, this is kind of annoying as it looks very bad. Is there any solution to this problem, I mean any css property for applying on links.[image: This image show exactly what I am saying]

Comment: Are you using some sort of reset? By default `a` have cursor pointer.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know this is a browser issue. Most browsers have the option to show a caret, my guess is that you accidently turned it on.

You could try using a different browser to see if it is a client-side issue. I would check that first, before you make any changes to your code.

Comment: but it is not with other websites, it is only with the one I am developing

Answer (score 0):

Something must have overridden the browsers styling of links.  Change it to pointer.

```
a{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: 'Reset' implies that `pointer` is the default. Actually, `auto` is the default. Not trying to be a d*ck, just pointing it out.

Comment: @F4r-20 reworded solution to not imply pointer is not default. So if auto is default why do anchors display with a pointer in almost every browser?  Is that the browsers overriding the default styling?